# Custom sorting of R datatable column for numbers stored as strings

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny dashboard in which I use the DataTable package (code closely following the approach in the [Shiny documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html)) to build my tables.

Everything is working fine but for aesthetic reasons I want to display the numbers with comma separators, so `1000000` is rendered `1,000,000`.

My approach so far has been use just reformat a numeric column like:

```
table$col <- formatC(table$col, format="d", big.mark=',')
```

and this works fine, but when I want to use the standard function to sort the tables in the webpage I get a sort in lexicographical order because the numbers are now encoded as strings.

Is there anyway to either modify the table sort function or encode the numbers in a way that they'll render with comma separators but the sort will behave as expected for these essentially numeric columns?

In case it is useful this could be reproduced as simply as adding this to a server.R file:

```
table <- morley
table$Speed <- formatC(table$Speed, format="d", big.mark=',')

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
  DT::datatable(table)
)
```

Comment: without proper code snippet it is pretty hard to help you (even your code is "similar" to Shiny documentation

Comment: I've added a code snippet but I don't think it adds much to the original problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 4.5 - Row Rendering of this DT document has your answer:
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

Comment: The `formatCurrency` function could be helpful too: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/DT.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When I need to format numerical values through the DT (DataTable) package, I use `formatCurrency` and I make sure to specify the `currency` parameter with an empty string. From there, the output can be tweaked with parameters such as `digits` and `mark`.

Below is an example of this function:

```
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(
   value1 = runif(10) * 10000,
   value2 = runif(10) * 100000,
   stringsAsFactors = F
 )

DT::datatable(data) %>%
   DT::formatCurrency(columns = "value1", currency =  "", mark = ",") %>%
   DT::formatCurrency(columns = "value2", currency =  "", mark = " ", digits = 0)
```

The output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L1jh.png)